# yii rewrite url not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I have this `.htaccess` script:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and the rewrite engine is on based on what i see in phpinfo. here is the screen for phpinfo

[image]

what could be the problem? all URL to controller/action is not found (404)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Apache must be enabled "AllowOverride all"

Also you can try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

In you main.php file located in protected/config/main.php, uncomment the url Manager 
add `'showScriptName'=>false,` that will enable the controller/action URL rewrite

`'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'             =>  '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>  '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'         =>  '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),`

Answer (score 0):

it's a device/OS error, i restarting my ubuntu machine then everything works well. thanks your for your answers.